# Authenticate cookie plugin remember me feature issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

Im using authenticate cakephp plugin in my project, i want to take advantage of the cookieauthenticate class of the plugin, the problem is that the plugin doesn't read the cookie to validate if it has exceeded the expiry date because when i change the date of my system the user is logged out even if the date of my cookie is not yet expired.
when i verified i've found that, it take only the the **CakePHP** cookie not my cookie that i have created.
here's my code that i use:
in the appcontroller my component contains this code

```
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'authenticate'=> array(
               'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'login',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
            ),
               'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'login',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ),
                    'columns' => array('login', 'email'),
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
                )
            ),
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'home',
                'prefix' => false)
        ),'Session','Cookie')
```

in my userscontrollers i got this code:

```
public function login() {
        $this->layout='login';

            if ($this->Auth->loggedIn() || $this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->_setCookie();
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));

    }

    protected function _setCookie() {
        if (!$this->request->data('User.remember_me')) {
            return false;
        }

        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->request->data('User.login'),
            'password' => $this->request->data('User.password')
        );
        $this->Cookie->write('User', $data, true, '+1 week');
        return true;
    }

    public function logout() {

        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->type('rijndael');
}
```

Im using cakephp 2.6.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain "the plugin doesn't read the cookie to validate if it has exceeded the expiry date". If the cookie has expired, then you would not expect it to still validate would you?

Comment: oki, the problem is my cookie that i created is not yet expired, and still the application log me out